# Custom loss function expects bool, but got float instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I received

> TypeError: Expected bool, got 0.0 of type 'float' instead.

In the first line of the following custom loss function

```
@tf.function
def reduce_fp(y_true, y_pred):

    mask_0 = tf.cast(y_true == 0.0, float)
    mask_1 = tf.cast(y_true == 1.0, float)


    dist_0 = y_pred * mask_0
    dist_1 = y_pred * mask_1

    discounted_0 = tf.reduce_mean(dist_0)
    discounted_1 = 1.0 - tf.reduce_max(dist_1)
    return discounted_0 + discounted_1
```

Can anyone help me explain and solve this issue? The error happens only if I run `model.fit` , if i pass   `tf.constant([...])` as arguments for y_true and y_pred, it runs fine. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

you must use `tf.math.eqaul(..)`

If you pass a `tf.constant(..)` , you run in eager execution and tensorflow does not build a graph.
if you are inside functions like "fit", you must stick to some additional syntax rules, because tensorflow cant read all of the python syntax (like comparsions)
even if you dont use the `@tf.function` decorator , if you use this function as a loss function for "fit", tensorflow will use it as a function inside its graph and it fails if you dont stick to the syntax.